# Django REST Framework - return a value from get_queryset?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return a `value` from `get_queryset`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
   if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        return StockPriceModel.objects.order_by('ticker').distinct()
   elif not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('in')
        print(self.request.data)
        last_price = StockPriceModel.objects.all().filter(
                ticker=self.request.data['ticker']).order_by('-last_date_time')[0].last_price
        print(last_price)
        return last_price
```

last price gets printed without an issue.

In `return` I get various errors:

> TypeError at /api/stock-prices-upload/
> 'float' object is not iterable

If I try to `return` till:

```
StockPriceModel.objects.all().filter(
                ticker=self.request.data['ticker']).order_by('-last_date_time')
```

It works.

As soon as I try to return just the `0` position queryset I get errors.

I assume this is because `get_queryset` is supposed to return a `queryset`. Not sure how to return just the value.

Edit:

I am now trying to get only the latest row i.e. `[0]` form the data but still getting the same errors i.e.

> StockPriceModel object is not iterable

```
# The current output if I don't add the [0] i.e. try to get the last row of data

[{"id":23,"last_price":"395.2","name":null,"country":null,"sector":null,"industry":null,"ticker":"HINDALCO","high_price":null,"last_date_time":"2022-10-20T15:58:26+04:00","created_at":"2022-10-20T23:20:37.499166+04:00"},{"id":1717,"last_price":"437.5","name":null,"country":null,"sector":null,"industry":null,"ticker":"HINDALCO","high_price":438.9,"last_date_time":"2022-11-07T15:53:41+04:00","created_at":"2022-11-07T14:26:40.763060+04:00"}]
```

Expected response:

```
[{"id":1717,"last_price":"437.5","name":null,"country":null,"sector":null,"industry":null,"ticker":"HINDALCO","high_price":438.9,"last_date_time":"2022-11-07T15:53:41+04:00","created_at":"2022-11-07T14:26:40.763060+04:00"}]
```

I have tried using `last`, `get` etc. Just won't work.

Comment: I think this is a bit of an anti-pattern in DRF architecture. For all the underlying ViewSet magic to work (Can't see your whole class..not sure what you're Sub'ing) you'll need to return a QuerySet. If you just want to return a single field- this should be handled in your Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Because, `get_queryset()` always return a queryset of objects or a list of objects.

You cannot return an object or a field from the `get_queryset` method.

the `last_price` value will be printed, but it is a field value and therefore the `get_queryset` method will not return it.

When you add `[0]`, it takes the first object from the filtered queryset. Till that point, it is a queryset of objects.

Comment: What would be the correct way to get the `value`? Thanks

Comment: could you please share this complete view class?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly to post, but editing the question. I am trying to return the `[0]` row/queryset but I get an error `'StockPriceModel' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, and I am sure there must be a better way to do this.

I wanted to get `return` of either a single row (last_date_time) based or the `last_price` value.

I wrapped the query:

```
# removed the .last_price
last_price = StockPriceModel.objects.all().filter(
                ticker=self.request.data['ticker']).order_by('-last_date_time')[0]
last_price = [last_price] # made it into a list, i.e. iterable
return last_price
```

And now I can get the last row.